# how to injection .net elements from page or file to onther at run time

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dynamic

for example i have this code in ex1.aspx :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <!-- CODE1: some gridview or other asp elements here -->
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:updatepanel>
</form>
```

and i have this code in other page ex2.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <!-- injection CODE1 to here in run time -->
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:updatepanel>
</form>
```

how can i get the CODE1 inside the ex2.aspx updatepanel in run time ?
for example when i click on some asp:button "clickToLoadGridView"

**edit:**
i tried already:
- user control ascx - but the problame is that there is conflict with form runat server. for example if i load a gridview with connection to database it will not work. i guess he lose the connection when he return from server.

the code i tried to load a gridview ascx is:

```
    using (Page objPage = new Page())
    {
        UserControl uControl = (UserControl)objPage.LoadControl("GridView.ascx");
        objPage.Controls.Add(uControl);
        using (StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(objPage, sWriter, false);
            return sWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

after it returned i append with jquery the code to the html.
then i can see only the first page of the gridview . but when if the grid view is paging and i click on the second button page i get page "This webpage is not available" .

Comment: -Create user control

Comment: i tried user control but i found onther error i will edit my massege and ill explain what i tried already.